# Positive definite kernels on categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, machine-learning, kernels

I'm wondering if there is any work on studying [positive definite kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel) on (the objects of a) category. By this I mean for a category $\mathcal{C}$, find a function

$$
K: Ob\mathcal{C} \times Ob\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$

such that for any finite subset $\{ A_i \}_{i \in I} \subset Ob\mathcal{C}$, the matrix $K[I] = [K(A_i, A_j)]_{i, j \in  I}$ is positive definite over the reals. Searching the internet for this has been tricky because of the existing notion of a kernel in category theory.

I think this would be interesting because we could then construct the [Reproducing kernel Hilbert Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) (RHKS) $H$, and essentially be able to think of the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ as elements of $H$.

[Graph kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_kernel) are an area of study in machine learning, so there is some precedent for this kind of thing.

I know there is nothing stopping me from studying such a thing, but I didn't know if there was any literature on the subject. Or is there maybe a theorem showing that any such $K$ are trivial, or none exist for certain classes of categories?

For an example, I think we can form a positive definite kernel if we have a category $\mathcal{C}$ with a finite (and nonzero) number of objects. For $A, B \in Ob\mathcal{C}$, set

$$
K(A, B) = \max\{ \#Ob\mathcal{C'}/\#Ob\mathcal{C} \mid \mathcal{C'} \text{ is a full subcategory of } \mathcal{C} \text{ containing } A \text{ and } B \text{ s.t. } Hom_{\mathcal{C'}}(A, -) \simeq Hom_{\mathcal{C'}}(B, -) \}
$$

where the $\simeq$ here denotes a natural isomorphism between functors. The we have that $0 \leq K(A, B) \leq 1 \hspace{3pt} \forall A, B \in Ob\mathcal{C}$, and $K(A, B) = 1 \iff A \simeq B$ in $\mathcal{C}$. Thus if we have a subset $\{ A_i \}_{i \in I} \subset Ob\mathcal{C}$, then $K[I]$ is a real-valued symmetric matrix, and thus has real eigenvalues. For a fixed $i \in I$, we have that $0 \leq \sum_{j \neq i} |K(A_i, A_j)| \leq \#I - 1$. Then by the Gershgorin circle theorem, the eigenvalues of $K[I]$ lie between $2 - \#I$ and $\#I$. Then define the function

$$
\tilde{K}(A, B) = \begin{cases} 
\#Ob\mathcal{C} \text{ if } A \simeq B \\
K(A, B) \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

The eigenvalues of $\tilde{K}[I]$ are (again by Gershgorin circle theorem) between $\#Ob\mathcal{C} - \#I + 1$ and $\#Ob\mathcal{C} + \#I -1$, making it a positive definite matrix, and $\tilde{K}$ a positive definite kernel.

The function $\tilde{K}$ is contrived and probably extremely difficult to compute. But are there other similar constructions? Or assumptions/structures on the category $\mathcal{C}$ that allow more practical kernels (e.g. Abelian, monoidal, enriched)? Or is the study of kernels on categories better handled as a case by case scenario?

Comment: $K$ doesn't even have to use any of the data of the category other than the objects? I can give any positive definite kernel on a set of the right cardinality?

Comment: hmm, that's a good point. i guess ideally i'd want $K$ to use the morphisms in some way. The entry $K(A, B)$ is usually quantifying some sort of notion of similarity between $A$ and $B$. I'm not sure what constraints to impose in general though